# Disabling third party login in social comment plugin

Tags: comments, facebook-social-plugins

I'm using the social comments plugin in my Facebook app.

In the plugin's documentation it says that the third party login can be disabled in the setting section of the plugin.

> How do I enable users to comment using other login providers?
>
> On the settings section of the plugin, you can choose to enable third party login on your comments boxes. Currently this will enable users to comment using a Yahoo!, AOL or Hotmail account.

Since the only section that I could find relating the plugin is the moderation tools, I'm assuming that is the "settings section of the plugin".

[Moderation Tools](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments)

Here is the screen that is shown when I click under settings for my application:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvwQg.jpg]

I have the "Other login providers" option disabled but it is still appearing in the comment box in my application.

Maybe there is a parameter or a method that I can use to achieve this or maybe I didn't find the correct settings section of the plugin.

Comment: This option is disabled by default, have you enabled it before?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your comment box isn't inheriting any settings from the page itself.  When I look at the settings on my comments box there is a section titled "Settings inherited from ...."